# Can I install attic ladder perpendicular to joists?

Tags: attic, joists, cutting, ladder

I only have one area in old house on the 3rd floor where I can put a pull down attic ladder. That is a narrow hallway but the ladder would need to be installed perpendicular to joists. It is an old house 1899. I have some photos of attic if that will help to answer my question. There is insulation but you can see the joists under there running perpendicular to way I need ladder. I would have to cut 3 joists. Can I safely do this?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I know the question I have to ask is off topic, but is the insulation blown cellulose or vermiculite? Or perhaps cellulose over vermiculite?

Comment: cellulose - no vermiculite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can you will need to frame in the opening to the existing framework, I would suggest new work in this case to be larger or thicker as today’s wood is total crap compared to your construction. What I mean if you have 2x6 in that old wood I would go with 2x8 or 4x6 ,, sounds funny but count the rings on your boards and today’s boards will be 1/3 to 1/4 so a larger board is a good idea. but it can be done, I have added pull downs on a couple of Victorians but most had stairways although very narrow. If it is a registered home get approval first!!!!  You can loose your tax status in some locations if the structure is modified.

Comment: How do you know that the joists are not preventing the walls from spreading? Could they be structural as well as holding up the ceiling?

Comment: If properly boxed in the new framework will prevent problems.

Comment: Yes, the wood in this old house is very hard & strong. Hard to even drill through it. Its not on historical register (on purpose) for that very reason! Thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI , I have had found hard wood studs in several Victorians. I ended up having to drill and use screws as nails were useless because that old oak was like rock.

Comment: Hi Ed - Where can I find a good book or guide on how to properly frame openings like this or other projects?

Comment: I gave my son in law a book “carpentry and building construction“ book many years ago that he uses it was written by John feirer and Gilbert hutchings. He uses that all the time, sorry it took a while to reply but I did not remember the name he just texted it to me. I looked for a while before getting him that book I chose it because it was well detailed, he still asks questions if he is not sure but he says he doesn’t feel dumb any more because he looks things up and then asks how I would do it , most time the same.

Comment: I'm new to all of this & need as much info as possible. Thanks much!

Comment: @rae be careful around that knob and tube wiring, I just noticed it, it looks to be in good shape but very old and the insulation is brittle.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ed Beal. I have an electrician handling that. We think its dead but we're going to make sure and remove it if can. Found good used hard copy of that book on Amazon and its on the way to me! :)

Comment: Awesome, my son in law used to get uncomfortable when my other son was here that grew up doing things with me, after all these years his book is well worn but he still uses it. Replacing that K&T makes sense to me but it is a good product if not overloaded. I have done quite a few repairs maintaining old Victorians, if you demo it save the tubes and any old switches , doorbell transformer and fixtures, some of these are worth a surprising amount of $ in working condition.

Comment: Wow. Never would have known that. Will do.